# Particle spawn on collision spawns too many particles

Tags: unity, collision-detection, particles

So i have the following code:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
        {
            if (contact.otherCollider.CompareTag("Ground"))
            {
                //Instantiate your particle system here.
                Instantiate(Effect, contact.point, Quaternion.identity);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now this works great however it spawns way too many particles (as the animation I am doing with the item hits the ground a lot).

Is there a way to limit the particles in a sensible way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using object pooling to reduce the amount of runtime spawning & despawning you do. If you create one object to manage the pool, through which all spawning requests are routed, then you also have a central place where you can manage those spawns and enforce the limits of your choosing.

For instance, we could have something that looks like this:

```
public class EffectPool : MonoBehaviour {

    // Inspector parameters to control what effect(s) to spawn, and how many.
    public ParticleSystem effectPrefab;
    public int maxInstances = 20;
    public int maxSpawnsPerFrame = 3;

    // Users will hold a reference to the prefab of the pool,
    // but we'll spawn an instance in the scene & route requests to it so that
    // it can handle scene events, and get cleaned up when we leave the scene.    
    EffectPool _sceneInstance;

    // Internally we won't spawn immediately/eagerly,
    // just queue-up requests to handle in a batch.
    struct SpawnRequest {
        public readonly Vector3 position;
        public readonly Quaternion orientation;
        public SpawnReques(Vector3 position, Quaternion orientation) {
            this.position = position;
            this.orientation = orientation;
        }
    }

    // Internal variables to keep track of the object pool state.
    List<SpawnRequest> _requests;
    ParticleSystem[] _effectInstances;
    int _nextSpawnIndex;

    // Scripts that want an effect to spawn call this.
    public void RequestSpawn(Vector3 position, Quaternion orientation) {
        // Ensure we have a pool in a loaded scene. If not, make one.
        if(_sceneInstance == null)
            _sceneInstance = Instantiate(this);

        // Ask the scene instance to queue-up this spawn request.
        sceneInstance.LogRequest(new SpawnRequest(position, orientation));
    }

    // Initialize a new object pool.
    void Awake() {
        _sceneInstance = this;
        _instances = new ParticleSystem[maxInstances];
        for(int i = 0; i < maxInstances; i++) {
            _instances[i] = Instantiate(effectPrefab);
            _instances[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    // Queue requests to process at the end of the frame.
    void LogRequest(SpawnRequest request) {
        _requests.Add(request)
    }

    // At the end of the frame, we have all the requests that have come in,
    // and we can control how to prune / combine them to limit spawns.
    void LateUpdate() {
        // Here, if we're over our spawning budget, 
        // we'll just choose at random some requests to not service.
        while(_requests.Count > maxSpawnsPerFrame) {
            _requests.RemoveAt(Random.Range(0, _requests.Count));
        }

        // Now we're within spawning budget. Spawn requested items.
        foreach(var request in _requests) {
            Spawn(request);
        }

        // Clear the request queue for next frame.
        _requests.Clear();
    }

    // Recycle effect instances from our pool.
    void Spawn(SpawnRequest request) {
        var effect = _instances[_nextSpawnIndex];
        _nextSpawnIndex = (_nextSpawnIndex + 1) % _instances.Length;

        // You may want to log a warning here - this is a sign your pool is too small
        // for the length of your effects and the number that are active.
        if(effect.isPlaying)
           effect.Stop(true);

        effect.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(request.position, request.orientation);
        effect.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        effect.Play(true);
    }
}
```

Here for simplicity I'm using a fairly naive rule - enforcing a maximum number of new effects per frame, and randomly weeding-out requests until we reach that number. This already gives us benefits over handling the budgeting in each collision individually though:

- We know how many total particles we need to spawn before we start pruning them, so we don't exhibit a bias (say, if the contacts are processed left to right, we don't consistently spend all our budget on the effects on the left side and leave none for the right)
- We can coordinate spawns across multiple FixedUpdates / multiple collisions in a single frame.
- We can coordinate spawns across many instances of scripts that use this effect.

From here, you can iterate on the spawning rule to dial in on the right behaviour for your needs. For instance...

- You might want to limit the density of particles in any one place, by bucketing spawn requests by position, and pruning down to one effect instance per bucket.
- You might want to coordinate spawns over time - for instance, sharing budget from one frame to the next, so an object that's continually spawning gets its overall rate throttled.
- You might want to reserve a fraction of your pool as "ready to spawn" - as your pool utilization gets high, you can run through the oldest instances and tell them to stop emitting / fade them out, so they're ready to spawn to serve new requests without popping.
- You might want to randomize one of multiple effects to spawn for variety, or use your budget to select whether to spawn an expensive / high-fidelity effect (eg. with sounds attached), or a cheaper background "filler" effect to keep from overwhelming the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I'd keep a count per collision. You could implement the following:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
int particleCount = 0;

    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        if (contact.otherCollider.CompareTag("Ground"))
        {
            //Instantiate your particle system here.
            Instantiate(Effect, contact.point, Quaternion.identity);
            particleCount++;
        }
        if (particleCount > MAX_PARTICLES) break;
    }
}
```

A slightly nicer version of the code would be to use a regular for loop, instead of a foreach, and access the contact point using the index.

Alternatively if you're wanting to limit the particles generated in general, rather than per collision, you could have some sort of random number generated before starting the for loop, and use that as the chance that particles would appear.